# Parsing string and creating json format then save to textfile

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, string

I want to create a json text and save it to textfile. Here's is my edited code so far. I want to have output in jsonFormat.txt must contain these strings {"Fname": "John low","Mname":"Bajud", "Lname": "Saddy"}.

```
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/jsonFormat.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        String delim = "\\|";
        String[] temp;
        String temp2;
        String data ="|Fname:John low|Mname:Bajud|Lname:Saddy|";

        data = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1);
        temp2 = data.split(delim);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

         for(int index=0;index < temp2.length() ;index++){
             String[] sub_temp2 = temp2[index].split(":");
             jsonObject.put(sub_temp2[0],sub_temp2[1]);
         }  

         FileOutputStream fOuts = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
         OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOuts);
         myOutWriter.append(jsonObject.toString());
         myOutWriter.close();
         fOuts.close();
```

I decided to solve my problem and after of struggles I've come up a solution :) Here's my Solution of the problem above :)

```
 try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/jsonFormat.txt");
        FileOutputStream fOuts = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        myFile.createNewFile();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        String delim = "\\|";
        String delim2 = "\\:";
        String[] temp;
        String[] temp2;
        String[] sub;
        String data = "|Fname:James Bryan|Mname:Baguio|Lname:Juventud|Age:21|Gender:Male|Fname:James Bryan|Mname:Baguio|Lname:Juventud|Age:21|Gender:Male|";

        data = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1);
        temp2 = data.split(delim);
        //System.out.print(temp2[1]+"\n"); = Fname:James Bryan
        builder.append("{");

        int k=1;
        for(int i=0;i<temp2.length;i++){
            //System.out.print(temp2[i]+"\n");
            sub = temp2[i].split(delim2);
            for(int x=0;x<sub.length;x++){
                builder.append("\"");
                builder.append(sub[x]);
                builder.append("\"");

                if(k<2){
                    builder.append(":");
                    k++;
                }
                else
                    k--;
            }
            builder.append(",");
        }
        builder.append("}");

        String newData = builder.substring(0, builder.length()-2);
        builder2.append(newData);
        builder2.append("}");
        //System.out.println(builder2.toString());
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOuts);
        myOutWriter.append(builder2);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOuts.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Output: JSON String textfile

```
 {"Fname": "James Bryan","Mname": "Baguio","Lname": "Juventud","Age": "21","Gender": "Male","Fname": "James Bryan","Mname": "Baguio","Lname": "Juventud","Age": "21","Gender": "Male"}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code? It should not compile as `temp2` should be a String array.

Comment: Do you have the data in the jsonObject, at least?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code does not even compile.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
temp2 = data.split(delim);
```

will not work because your `delim` is wrong

try

```
String delim = "\\|";
```

and `temp2` should be a String array;

Comment: ok. I'll try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, The code has multiple issues.

1. *temp2* needs to be a String array
2. for loop should limit on "temp2.length" not length()
3. The delimiter you use "[|]" is incorrect. You can split just on the pipe "|" without any attempt to escape pipe.

I suggest to revisit the code and understand what is it doing and try to compile and resolve issues one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not telling how to convert string to json but you try this

```
public void saveContentToDisk(Context context,
            String filename, String json) {
String data = null;
if (json != null && !json.isEmpty()) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        data = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<String>() {
        }.getType());    
    }
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File(
                    context.getExternalCacheDir(), filename));
            out.write(data);
            out.close();
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saved data to disk " + filename);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error saving data to disk, " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir ? I'm new in java and android but i'll try to compile your code :)

Comment: Sir ? is this code will automatically create json out of my string ?

Comment: it will give you string from json data and save to file

Comment: I've worked this project since last day but I can't generate a json string :( Is my work sir possible to generate json string ?

Comment: yes you have to generate json string